# Force Exit app on Android causes App to Freeze when reopened

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, react-native

It is hard to paste all the code because I do not exactly know what is happening. My app is using a Tab Navigator as it's main navigation, and it works perfectly fine when I run it normally.

HOWEVER,

Whenever I forcefully quit it using the Android left button, it stops working when I reopen it.

Once it is re-open, I am able to swipe through all my tabs but each screen is FROZEN. I cannot click anything and the Tab Navigator does not update (it shows the initialRoute still selected).

I am very confused on what is causing the problem, my initial guess would be something to do with listeners but I really don't know which part of my app causes this. I have added the Firebase tag for this reason. I would like to try turning off all my listeners if the app is force closed, but I don't know if this is possible.

Other details:
I mostly use 'on' listeners.

Thanks.

Comment: I sort of had similar problem with react-navigation (don't know if you are using it or not). I solved it with `{swipeEnabled:false, animationEnabled:false}` There is also a [github issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1805) about it